# Integrating Electron with Angular 17

Tags: angular, electron, angular17

I have a simple Angular 15 app that uses Electron and works great. I'm trying to upgrade it to Angular 17 and the latest Electron. I'm getting a strange error when I run `npm run electron`. I'm not sure why `styles.css` isn't found or what's wrong with the code in my main (home) router.

[image: Error NG04002]

Here's a PR that shows the difference between Angular 15 and 17 versions: https://github.com/mraible/ng-demo/pull/139

I changed the [`main.js`](https://github.com/mraible/ng-demo/pull/139/files#diff-58417e0f781b6656949d37258c8b9052ed266e2eb7a5163cad7b0863e6b2916a) file and the `build.files` section in `package.json` since the build directory is now `dist/ng-demo/browser` instead of `dist/ng-demo`. Neither seems to help.

Steps to reproduce:

For Angular 15, `git clone -b electron https://github.com/mraible/ng-demo`, followed by `npm ci && npm run electron`. Everything works fine with this version.

With Angular 17, you see the error in the screenshot above after running these commands:

```
git clone -b electron-v17 https://github.com/mraible/ng-demo
cd ng-demo
npm i
npm run electron
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, have you updated just Angular or also Electron?

Comment: I've updated it to the latest version of Electron, too. https://github.com/mraible/ng-demo/blob/electron-v17/package.json#L55-L56

Comment: Have you tried to figure out if you problem comes from the update of Angular or Electron?

Comment: It seems related to Angular 17 because I tried my `electron` branch with Angular 15 and the latest version of Electron (27.1.3), and it works fine.

Comment: Alright, please share the path to the css file showing in the network tab of the dev console. I think it's an useful information for people to help you.

Comment: I fixed the 404 for `styles.css`. You can see the `app.component.ts` and its template are loading OK because the title of the app is showing. It seems to fail when trying to load the `search` route. This works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure about what 404 you are refering to, nor what is the search route.